# Creating VBA script in MS-Word 2010 to replace multiple line breaks with comma(,)

Tags: vba, ms-word

1.I am trying to create a VBA script to check quality of the documents.
2.If there are any spaces or linebreaks after a word all should be replaced by comma(**,**).**i.e**:I don't want any spaces to be present before comma(**,**)
**Example:**

`Before running VBA script`
**abc**[space]
[linebreak]
**,**

`After running  VBA script`
**abc** **,**

`Desired Result which I am expecting`
**abc,**

I have tried below code,but i am not getting any clue to further work on it,The below VBA script detects only one linebreak.
I want to create a VBA script that detects multiple linebreaks and give me the desired result.

```
    Sub Replace1()
    '
    ' Replace1 Macro
    '
    '
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p,"
    .Replacement.Text = ","
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you find text like so:

```
.Text = "[ ^13]{1,},"
```

and set wild cards to true:

```
.MatchWildcards = True
```

Also make sure the cursor starts at the beginning of the document. You can do so by adding this before Find begins in your VBA:

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
```

**Explanation:**
`[ ^13]` matches a space OR a paragraph marker (character `^13`). `{1,}` looks for one or more repetitions and, unlike `@`, it is greedy.